# How do I serve a static file with httprouter with correct MIME type?

Tags: json, go, mime-types, static-files, raml

I'm using the [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) Go library to implement a REST API service, and I decided to try [ServeFiles](https://godoc.org/github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter#Router.ServeFiles) to serve some schema files associated with my API. I note that it uses Go's handy built-in [net/http](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package under the hood for serving static files.

It works almost perfectly, except for one nit: RAML files are served with the content type `text/plain`. I note, however, that the JSON schema files I have get served with `application/json`, so clearly there's some sort of MIME type association going on with the static file service. Is there a way to configure it to detect my RAML file as such, and serve it with, say, the content type `application/raml+yaml` instead?

I follow the usual convention of `.raml` file extensions for the RAML files and `.json` for the JSON schemas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a way to do this. The `net/http` library uses the `mime` library under the hood to detect content types. In particular, it uses [TypeByExtension](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#TypeByExtension) to figure out whether the file extension is associated with a known content type. To configure that, simply call [AddExtensionType](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#AddExtensionType), say, where you register your static file routing during app startup.